# Find the row that contain multiple values in other column

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

### Question

I have a dataframe that have two columns: `NO` and `CODE`. I am trying to find `NO` that contain two type of `CODE`. How can I make it?

### The codes look like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'NO': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f'], 'CODE': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '4', '1', '4', '1', '4', '4', '1', '4', '1']})

Out[1]: 
   NO CODE
0   a    1
1   a    1
2   b    1
3   b    1
4   c    4
5   c    1
6   d    4
7   d    1
8   e    4
9   e    4
10  e    1
11  f    4
12  f    1
```

### Expected result

```py
NO CODE
c  4
c  1
d  4
d  1
e  4
e  4
e  1
f  4
f  1
```

Any help will be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and [nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) to get number of unique values for CODE per NO. 
 Keep only rows that are greater than one and drop the transform column.

```
df['gt_1'] = df.groupby('NO').CODE.transform('nunique')

df.query('gt_1 > 1').drop('gt_1',axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

    NO  CODE
0   c   4
1   c   1
2   d   4
3   d   1
4   e   4
5   e   4
6   e   1
7   f   4
8   f   1
```

Another option: Use the [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration) function in groupby to get only rows where unique values is greater than one, then use the iloc method to extract only rows that meet criteria.

```
check = df.groupby('NO').CODE.filter(lambda x:x.nunique()>1).index

df.iloc[check]

    NO  CODE
4   c   4
5   c   1
6   d   4
7   d   1
8   e   4
9   e   4
10  e   1
11  f   4
12  f   1
```